# How to freeze Gem version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to freeze rubygems version in my rails application, as an dependency.

Can you guide me to how to freeze gem version(RubyGems)(not rails gem), in the rails application.

I have tried to create .gem-version file in the application folder, but it did not work for me.
Thanks

Comment: I want to freeze core gem version, for example if you type command gem --version, you get a gem version, want to freeze this with application.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There comes a default `gem` version with each Ruby version. What is wrong with that version for the Ruby version you are using?

Comment: currently we use 2.XX gem version, but problem with the new team members, as when they install rubygems by default downloaded version is > 3.X.X, and some gems like Zentest uses < 3.X.X version., any help would be appreciated.

Comment: install ruby by using RVM. And you can select what is the version you want. And rails application already having `gemfile.lock` , so when you run `bundle install` then it will install all ruby gems with already saved versions in gemfile.lock.

Comment: I want to freeze Core Gem version, not a particular gem, so when you type command gem -v, this version, I want to fix with my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to freeze ruby version in rails application then you can specify the ruby version in rails Gemfile. Just open the Gemfile and add `ruby "2.5.1"`, you can specify which version you want.

Once you specified the ruby version in Gemfile and it will give notice the developer like please install ruby specified version before `bundle install`. I hope it is what you expecting.

Comment: OP was not asking about ruby version, but rather version of rubygems